# what is the difference between multi-threading and async-await in Dart and how do i use it correctly?

Tags: multithreading, dart, async-await

I'm new to Dart language (but not to programming in general) and I find it hard to use async and await properly (make the code run the same way a multi-threaded code will). All the explanations I found didn't explain clearly how the code-flow works and what are its advantages.

Can someone please explain the difference between async-await and multi-threading and how to use it correctly?

Comment: Have you read: https://hackernoon.com/are-futures-in-dart-threads-2cdc5bd8063a ?

Comment: No, I haven't. Thanks